# What is Azure functions Cron Expression to trigger on specific dates of every month?

Tags: c#, regex, cron, azure-functions, timer-trigger

i have C# Timer Trigger Azure function, which i want to trigger at specific dates of every month. what should be the cron expression for it?

e.g. : trigger job at 8th and 20th date of each month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trigger can look something like:

starting with azure cron expression:

```
{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
```

The expression:

```
0 0 12 8,20 * ?
```

This will trigger a noon on the 8 and 20 each month

Comment: Thank you Peter, Just little improvement `0 0 0 8,20 * *`.